# Why do some special characters ("Ü") show up as encoded HTML entities (&#252;)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, special-characters

This is my `DetailView` and `SqlDataSource` :

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateRows="False" HeaderText="Rechnung Details" DataKeyNames="InvoiceID" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceID" HeaderText="Rechnungs Nummer" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="InvoiceID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Datum" SortExpression="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tell" HeaderText="Telefon" SortExpression="Tell" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Addresse" SortExpression="Address" ReadOnly="true"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Betrag" SortExpression="Amount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Paid" HeaderText="Bezahlter Betrag" SortExpression="Paid" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Rest" HeaderText="Rest" SortExpression="Rest" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PaymentType" HeaderText="Zahlungsart" SortExpression="PaymentType" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Shipped" HeaderText="erledigt" SortExpression="Shipped" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Bericht" SortExpression="Comment" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RechnungConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Invoice.[InvoiceID], Invoice.[CustomerID], Invoice.[Date], Invoice.[Amount], Invoice.[Paid], Invoice.[Rest], Invoice.[PaymentType], Invoice.[Shipped], Customer.[CustomerID], Customer.[Name], Customer.[Tell], Customer.[Address], Customer.[Comment] FROM [Invoice] INNER JOIN [Customer] ON Invoice.[CustomerID] = Customer.[CustomerID] WHERE Invoice.[InvoiceID] = @InvoiceID"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Invoice] SET Invoice.[Date]=@Date, Invoice.[Amount]=@Amount, Invoice.[Paid]=@Paid, Invoice.[PaymentType]=@PaymentType, Invoice.[Shipped]=@Shipped WHERE [InvoiceID]=@InvoiceID"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Invoice WHERE [InvoiceID] = @InvoiceID">
     <SelectParameters>
      <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="InvoiceID" QueryStringField="ID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and this is my Button For create PDF from DetailView's Data :

```
        protected void CreatePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string InvoiceID = DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
        string Date = DetailsView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text;
        //string Name = DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text;
        StreamReader srn = new StreamReader(DetailsView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
        string Name = srn.ReadToEnd();
        string Tell = DetailsView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Text;
        //string Address = DetailsView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Text;
        StreamReader sra = new StreamReader(DetailsView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Text, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
        string Address = sra.ReadToEnd();
        string Amount = DetailsView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Text;
        string TimeNow = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Date);




        string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("~/PDF/");
        string imagepath = Server.MapPath("~/Image/AlsterLogo.jpg");
        string pdfName = Name + " Rechnungs Nummer = " + InvoiceID;
        //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Export.pdf");
        //Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 15f, 15f, 30f, 30f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(Path.Combine(pdfpath, pdfName) + ".pdf" , FileMode.Create));
        pdfDoc.Open();

        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath);
        jpg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

        Font arial8U = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font arial8 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font arial10 = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font arial10B = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        table.TotalWidth = 500f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        float[] widths = new float[] { 325f , 175f };
        table.SetWidths(widths);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ASM Transporte Mundsburger Damm 38, 22087 Hamburg", arial8U));
        cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Herr/Frau/Firma", arial10));
        cell1.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Tel: 040-29 12 12", arial10));
        cell2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Fax: 040-29823820", arial10));
        cell3.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sachbearbeiter: S.Dadras", arial10));
        cell4.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("mail: dadras@alster-umzuege.de", arial8));
        cell5.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Rechnung-Nr: " + InvoiceID, arial10B));
        cell6.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        //cell6.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        PdfPCell cell7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Hamburg " + TimeNow, arial10));
        cell7.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;




        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.AddCell("");
        table.AddCell(cell1);
        table.AddCell("");
        table.AddCell(Name);
        table.AddCell(cell2);
        table.AddCell(Address);
        table.AddCell(cell3);
        table.AddCell("");
        table.AddCell(cell4);
        table.AddCell("");
        table.AddCell(cell5);
        table.AddCell("");
        table.AddCell(cell6);
        table.AddCell("");
        table.AddCell(cell7);


        pdfDoc.Add(jpg);
        pdfDoc.Add(table);
        pdfDoc.Close();
    }
```

Problem is when the PDF created it cant read Special Character's Like Ü ! how can i fix this ?!

Comment: What "can't read" the characters? *What does it read* or *what happens* instead?

Comment: for example it read FÜrth as F&#252;rth

Comment: *What* reads it as so? Which *expression* first shows said value (*use the debugger to look*)? How/where does it show up like that? (Also that is [HTML entity encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML).)

Comment: I've given a *huge* starting point with the title, but if expecting help make sure to answer the questions I've previously asked. Debugging - including isolating the cause/source/effect of the issue - is the responsibility of a programmer.

Comment: When i Click on the Create-PDF Button its create some reports from my DB and in that PDF show FÜrth as F&#252;rth !

Comment: So *where* (and what *expression/variable*) does the "&#252;" **first** appear? Use the debugger and monitor. This is debugging. Does the use of the PDF generator produce the transformation or is it from before (such as when obtaining the input from ASP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be as simple as using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) everywhere you're adding text to the pdf (or atleast where you're expecting special chars)